# Blazor display data from database

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a Blazor Page which simply displays some data from a database.

My markup looks like this:

```
@inject MyDataService service;

if(!MyData.Count() > 0) { <div>no data</div>}

else { //display data }
```

My code like this:

```
@ code {

       private List<MyData> MyData {get; set;} = new List<MyData>();

       protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    { 
         MyData = MyDataService.GetData();          
    }
}
```

This work but the problem is:

I see MyData displayed - then it shortly flips to "No Data" - then again I see MyData rendered

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think is due to pre-rendering.

Comment: Try to create a [mcve], using s short stub for GetData().